# Rearranging Windows Media Player auto inserted track information

Tags: windows-media-player

I have a few CD's that I've ripped to WMP.  The online database information is wrong for some CD's that I bought.  Cover art is right but **tracks in different orders**.

(This is WMP in Windows 8.1)

The track information is stored in a database.  It has a **WMDB** extension.

I'd like to fix the data in the database rather than editing through the UI.

How do I read and write queries **against that database**?

Failing that is there a sensible way of **modifying the remote data** and connecting to the modified version instead of the normal bad source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking for programmatic access to the WMDB database, this is possible through the [Windows Media Player Object Model API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (e.g. the [MediaCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd563833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object).

But why go the hard way and not just edit the data through the UI?

Comment: On the UI. In Win 8.1 it's quite cumbersome to swap all properties around for say 13 tracks, using the UI. (I've used it for a few titles, but checking through 40 properties is too much.)  I did have a look at the WMP SDK documentation (before posting the question). It's a potential fall back, if I can't directly edit the database.

Comment: Directly editing the database isn't possible since it's in an undocumented format. If you're looking for a way to quickly apply all tags of one song to another song, you could use the `Tag Copy` and `Tag Paste` commands in [Mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/).

Comment: Thanks Tim.  For anybody else who's tackling this.  I spent a few minutes exploring the Interfaces to the Media Player, in code.  Came up with 107 fields on the tracks I examined.  Judged that over half of these may be imported.  Probably not hard to take that through to a utility that does what's needed.  Will try out Mp3tag.

Comment: Since you're speaking of importing, the [Metadata Backup](http://www.dalepreston.com/Blog/2007/03/windows-media-player-metadata-backup.html) tool can export/import all WMP library info to/from XML, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Tim, the information you're providing exceeds my expectations.  Thanks.  I was indeed looking at ways of backing up data and synching between computers.  This tool looks like it's a good way.  (For others who are looking at the dB.  I did in fact start investigating what dB technology was used in the WMDB's.  The link about the backup tool, says it's unique, so that will also save me time (I won't do anything more).)